# Does there exist an integer $m$ which is not in the image of $D(n)=2n - \sigma(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $n$, and denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n$ by $D(n)=2n-\sigma(n)$.

Here is my question:

> Do there exist numbers $m$ which (provably) do not have any pre-images under $m=D(n)=2n-\sigma(n)$?

I am currently unable to come up with a specific example.

Comment: You might think that $3$ and $-1$ might be simpler than most, but apparently $-1$ is unsolved (it must be an odd square, and there are no known examples below $10^{35}$ - see R. K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Section B2. https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-0-387-26677-0#page/n91/mode/2up )

Comment: @Henry, what is the status for $3$?

Comment: I don't have access to the article, but this seems extremely relevant to the question: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mjms/1449161366.  The wording (not definitively) suggests that there is probably no $m$ that is currently known to lie outside of the range of $D$.

Comment: Is it known that there is an $m$ that does not appear?

Comment: @barto, I currently do not have an answer to that inquiry;  hence, my question in this MSE post.

Comment: Well there are two questions: "Does $D(n)$ reach all integers?" and the more difficult "Which integers do not appear?". The question suggests that the answer to the first one is known to be false.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  Editing my question in response to your last comment, @barto.