# Are there any numbers with deficiency 3

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering if there are any numbers $n$ with the property $\sigma(n)=2n-3$. Sequence [A033879](https://oeis.org/A033879) in the online encyclopedia of integer sequences lists the deficiency of $n$ for the first $16384$ terms and there is no such term where $a(n)=3$. Is this a coincidence or can we prove the nonexistence of numbers with deficiency 3?

Comment: It is also known that for the first $10^{10}$ natural numbers there's no number with deficiency $3$. Ref: Davis, Nichole, Dominic Klyve, and Nicole Kraght. "On the difference between an integer and the sum of its proper divisors." Involve, a Journal of Mathematics 6.4 (2013): 493-504.

Comment: Besides, in the same paper, the authors showed that $a(n)$ is odd iff $n = k^2$ or $2k^2$ for some integer $k$, which may also be used.

Comment: Also there is a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090864

Comment: Does OEIS list the deficiency negative if the given number is abundant ?

Comment: oeis does list negative deficiency if n is abundant